# Iphone 4 graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to design a background image for my app. The image should fill the iPhone screen.
What image size that will work for 3G and 4G?

A) 320 x 480.
B) 640 x 960.

I prefer to use B as it will have more quality, will 3G resize the image to fit?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Simply author both sizes and save the hi-res with a `@2x` suffix in the filename (like `background.png` and `background@2x.png`). iPhone 4 will use the hi-res image, older devices will stick to the ordinary one. See the docs for [`+[UIImage imageNamed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method looks in the system caches
>   for an image object with the specified
>   name and returns that object if it
>   exists. If a matching image object is
>   not already in the cache, this method
>   loads the image data from the
>   specified file, caches it, and then
>   returns the resulting object.
>
> On a device running iOS 4 or later,
>   the behavior is identical if the
>   device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If
>   the screen has a scale of 2.0, this
>   method first searches for an image
>   file with the same filename with an
>   @2x suffix appended to it. For
>   example, if the file’s name is button,
>   it first searches for button@2x. If it
>   finds a 2x, it loads that image and
>   sets the scale property of the
>   returned UIImage object to 2.0.
>   Otherwise, it loads the unmodified
>   filename and sets the scale property
>   to 1.0. See iOS Application
>   Programming Guide for more information
>   on supporting images with different
>   scale factors.

Also read the [appropriate part](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW1) of iOS Application Programming Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is trivial to resize the image to the proper size, you should prepare *both* 320×480 and 640×960 (and probably you need a 1024×768 for iPad too). In this way the system can choose the best image for that model.

Basically, you create a 320×480 `background.png` for the older models, and a 640×960 `background@2x.png` for retina display. Then load the image with

```
UIImage* backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
```

in this way, the system will choose the best resolution automatically.